# Windows 7 login screen not cloned by second display

Tags: windows-7, displayport, login-screen

Windows 7 Home-Edition (64-bit): Windows logon screen is only at VGA (TV connected) and not as clone at DVI (Digital Display connected)

Answer (score 4):

This is how it's designed to work (or at least it's been this way on all the Windows 7 machines I've used).

When you first turn on the machine or lock it only the primary monitor is active.

Comment: Confirming that this is by design.